# DS4 Stuck in Discovery (Bluetooth) Mode

Tags: ps4

After successfully pairing my DS4 with my Mac through USB, I attempted to do the same via Bluetooth.

The connection works, although it doesn't output data in a way that I can use it easily (through Max/MSP). I've been trying for the last hour to repair it with my PS4, but I can't get it out of the Bluetooth mode, even after holding down the reset button for 10 seconds.

The orange charging light comes on when it's plugged in, but it doesn't connect through USB at all. I don't really want to take it apart, and I've looked all over the web but haven't found a solution to the issue.

Comment: Try holding the PS button and Options at the same time for 10 seconds.

Comment: That doesn't have any effect either, in fact it turns the controller off (as in the blinking white 'search' light) straight away (by pressing the PS button).

Comment: @clappski you need to do it when the controller is already off. So with the controller off, press and hold the option button followed by the PS button.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too.
All you have to do is to connect the controller through
the USB to the ps4, and then unplug it.
It will reset and exit Bluetooth mode, and will work 
with the PS4 again normally

Answer (score 0):

I have not had experience with this problem, but my first thought would be that it is connecting to your mac when you try and connect it - try turning off the blutooth (or even just the mac itself) and then attempting to repair.

Answer (score 0):

If your contoller doesn't connect because it's stuck in bluetooth mode try getting another controller (a spare or a friend's) and then go on bluetooth devices and click forget the controller and then hold the ps and share button again and pair it to the PS4.

Also you can use remote play on your phone if you cant get a spare controller